# Помогите понять смысл афоризма

Tags: смысл

В чем смысл афоризма: "В моем словаре нет слова *невозможно*"?

Comment: Ссылку на источник афористичности этого афоризма можете дать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В моём словаре нет слова "невозможно".

Данный афоризм **выражает уверенность высказывающегося в его возможности совершить любое действие**, повествующий готов на что угодно.

Историки приписывают данное высказывание Наполеону Бонапарту.

Comment: "В моем словаре нет слов «невозможно», «не умею», «не могу»", — полная цитата https://notagram.ru/20-tsitat-sposobnyh-polnostyu-vas-izmenit/

Comment: @shampar Приведённая на этом сайте полная цитата, скорей всего, является домыслом. Слова «не умею» и «не могу», вероятно, прибавили для усиления мотивирующего эффекта. На французском языке цитата выглядит «Impossible n’est pas français _(невозможно не по-французски)_», и в ней нет ничего про «не умею» и «не могу».

Comment: @Eagle Всё возможно. Домыслом меньше, домыслом больше... Andrew Cool, например, сделал допущение, назвав высказывание афоризмом.

Comment: @shampar Я вот тоже не пойму, можно считать это афоризмом или нет. Я написал ниже свой ответ, с информацией об этих словах. Это не точный перевод того, что говорил Наполеон, а скорее вольная передача смысла. В афоризме, на мой взгляд, должна быть точная цитата, которую многократно повторяют. А кто такой Andrew Cool?

Comment: Вы у него спросите. У меня не получилось его разговорить.

Answer (score 0):

Слово «словарь» в данном высказывании имеет значение:

> **СЛОВА́РЬ**, *-я́, м.*
>
> 2. только ед. ч. **Совокупность слов, используемых кем-л.** или где-л.
>
>    ```
>    Воробейцев уже сносно говорил по-немецки — во всяком случае, располагал словарем из каких-нибудь ста пятидесяти слов, при помощи которых можно было вполне объясняться. Казакевич, Дом на площади. Я не люблю пустого словаря Любовных слов и жалких выражений: «Ты мой». «Твоя». «Люблю». Блок, В дюнах.
>    ```
>
> *[Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]*

*«В моем **словаре** нет слова „невозможно“» → «Я **не использую** слово „невозможно“».*

Слово «невозможно» может использоваться, как оправдание нежелания что-то предпринимать, лени.

Не использовать слово «невозможно», значит не оправдывать своё бездействие, недостижение чего-то мнимой невозможностью, а брать и делать.

---

Однако Наполеон именно так, дословно, не говорил. Во французской Википедии цитата приведена в следуем виде:

> «Impossible n'est pas français» est une citation prêtée à Napoléon.
>
> *«Невозможно не по-французски» — цитата приписываемая Наполеону I.*
>
> [[fr.wikipedia.org](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_n%27est_pas_fran%C3%A7ais)]

Изначально о «невозможно» Наполеон сказал так: *«Как? Невозможно! Я не знаю этого слова! Для моих поляков не должно быть ничего невозможного!»*:

> En novembre 1808, Napoléon est en route pour prendre Madrid lors de la guerre d'Espagne. Son armée se trouve bloquée au pied de l'étroit col de Somosierra, dans la sierra de Guadarrama, par quatre batteries espagnoles et des tireurs embusqués qui prennent le défilé en enfilade. L'empereur décide alors d'envoyer un escadron de chevau-légers polonais prendre les batteries espagnoles. Mais ses lieutenants lui disent que cela est « impossible ». **Napoléon leur répond alors : « comment ? Impossible ! Je ne connais point ce mot là ! Il ne doit y avoir pour mes Polonais rien d'impossible ! ».** L'escadron, au prix de lourdes pertes, arrive à prendre le col.
>
> Примеренный перевод:
> *В ноябре 1808 года во время войны с Испанией Наполеон находился на пути к взятию Мадрида. Его армия оказалась заблокирована у подножия узкого прохода Сомосьерра в горах Гвадаррама четырьмя испанскими батареями и снайперами, которые шли друг за другом. Затем император решает послать эскадрон польской лёгкой кавалерии для захвата испанских батарей. Но его помощники говорят ему, что это «невозможно». **Наполеон тогда ответил им: «Как? Невозможно! Я не знаю этого слова! Для моих поляков не должно быть ничего невозможного!».** Эскадрону ценой больших потерь удаётся взять перевал.*
>
> [[fr.wikipedia.org](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_n%27est_pas_fran%C3%A7ais)]

Позже слова приобрели немого другой вид:

> L'expression impériale circule alors dans l'armée puis arrive jusqu'à la Cour. Plus tard, alors que Fouché indique à l'Empereur qu'il est impossible de convaincre le tsar Alexandre Ier de chasser les émigrés français de Russie, Napoléon lui fait une réponse similaire à celle faite en Espagne. Fouché répond alors : **« en effet, j'aurais dû me rappeler que Votre Majesté nous a appris que le mot impossible n'est pas français. »**. Napoléon écrit ensuite en juillet 1813 au général Le Marois, commandant la ville de Magdebourg qui jugeait impossible de tenir la cité face à l'ennemi : **« c'est impossible m'écrivez-vous ; cela n'est pas français. »**
>
> Mentionnée en 1837 dans ses mémoires par le général de Caulaincourt3, l'expression est popularisée par Balzac, qui publie en 1838 Maximes et pensées de Napoléon.
>
> Примеренный перевод:
> *Выражение императора затем распространилось в армии, а затем достигло двора.  Позже, когда Фуше указывает императору, что невозможно убедить царя Александра I изгнать французских эмигрантов из России, Наполеон дает ему ответ, аналогичный тому, что был дан в Испании. Затем Фуше отвечает: **«На самом деле, я должен был помнить, что Ваше Величество научило нас, что слово „невозможно“ не французское»**. Затем Наполеон написал в июле 1813 года генералу Ле Маруа, командующему городом Магдебург, который считал невозможным удержать город против врага: **«Это невозможно, вы пишите мне; это не по-французски»**.*
>
> *Как упоминает в 1837 году в своих мемуарах генерал де Коленкур, это выражение популяризировал Бальзак, опубликовавший в 1838 году «Максимы и мысли Наполеона».*
>
> [[fr.wikipedia.org](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_n%27est_pas_fran%C3%A7ais)]

Исходя из вышесказанного, можно сделать вывод, что Наполеон вкладывал в эти слова смысл: *Нет ничего невозможного*.

Скорее всего, такое понимание пришло к нему в результате большого количества побед:

> CCXLIX
>
> Не однажды в течение моей кампании 1814 г. **я задумывался о том, что
> для моих солдат нет ничего невозможного**: они снискали себе бессмертное
> имя. В превратностях же судьбы меня повсюду сопровождала слава.
>
> [[Максимы и мысли узника Святой Елены. Рукопись, найденная в бумагах
> Лас Каза](http://www.museum.ru/museum/1812/Library/laskas/index.html)]

Однако у него есть и другая максима:

> XLII
>
> Будучи смелым, можно решиться на что угодно, **но невозможно все довести
> до конца**.
>
> [[Максимы и мысли узника Святой Елены. Рукопись, найденная в бумагах
> Лас Каза](http://www.museum.ru/museum/1812/Library/laskas/index.html)]

Скорей всего, это мысль уже позднего разочарованного Наполеона, потерпевшего поражение.

---

Сейчас приведённые вами слова Наполеона есть на многих сайтах среди цитат для вдохновения.

Когда смотришь на это, вспоминается отрывок из романа «Отцы и дети» И. С. Тургенева:

> — Наполеоновское правило, батюшка, наполеоновское, — подхватил Василий
> Иванович и пошел с туза.
>
> **— Оно же и довело его до острова Святыя Елены**, — промолвил отец
> Алексей и покрыл его туза козырем.

Тут под правилом понимается не цитата про слово «невозможно», однако эта мысль может быть справедлива и по отношению к ней. Учитывая финал, к которому пришёл Наполеон, выгляди странным использование его идей для вдохновения. Кроме того, невозможного, как в первом случае употребления этих слов в горах Гвадаррама, он достигал ценой огромного количества жизней.

---

**Примечание:**

*Я не знаю французского языка, переводы в этом ответе могут быть неточными.*